# how to open angular app on mobile device with same network

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, mean

I have an Angular App I am trying to open it on mobile with the same network
I try `ng serve --host <my IP> or ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` 
this is working fine but the problem is **this application is making a request to Nodejs API which is running on a different port (3000)** and when I run this app on the desktop it works fine but **on mobile API data is not showing** only the angular part is visible

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are talking about just development configuration, because these tools aren't supposed to be used on production.

to easilly bound together FE and BE on dev configuration I would propose to add API_URL to environment.ts

```
// environment.ts
export const environment = {
  API_URL: '/api'
}
```

use this prefix for your calls

```
export class MyService {
 ...
 getData() {
   return this.http.get<Data>(`${API_URL}/data`)
 }
}
```

and setup a development proxy onfiguration with content

```
// proxy.conf.json
{
 "/api/*": {
   "target": "http://localhost:3000/"
   "pathRewrite": {
     "^/api": ""
   }
 }
}
```

and add `"proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"` to angular.json serve -> development configuration

Comment: thank I got your point it's really helpful,  I am using this :- export const environment = {
  API_URL: 'export const environment = {
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
}'
} but I think I need to use proxy.conf.json file

Comment: you need to follow all of the points that I've described. You can't have `API_URL: 'localhost:3000'` because your client is going to be ran on another device(in your case it is mobile phone) and queries would be run to the mobile phone itself. You have to make it relative like in the answer: `API_URL: '/api'`. or, it could bee your network ip address, if your devices are in the same network `API_URL: 'http://192.168.0.40:3000'`. But I would still prefer relative path and a proxy, as it is more reliable

Comment: okay got it. thank a lot for responding fast